Error retrieving access token GaxiosError: invalid_grant for gmail using googleapis and nodemailer
Configured my google account to generate client_id, client_secret, etc.,
Added all the scopes in OAuth concent screen
All scopes added in OAuth concent screen
Tested in OAuth 2.0 playground it worked fine.
POST /token HTTP/1.1
Host: oauth2.googleapis.com
Content-length: 318
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
user-agent: google-oauth-playground

code=xxxxxxxxxxx&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Foauthplayground&client_id=xxxxxxx&client_secret=xxxxxxxxx&scope=&grant_type=authorization_code

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-length: 455
X-xss-protection: 0
X-content-type-options: nosniff
Transfer-encoding: chunked
Expires: Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Vary: Origin, X-Origin, Referer
Server: scaffolding on HTTPServer2
-content-encoding: gzip
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Date: Thu, 11 Jul 2024 10:00:05 GMT
X-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
Alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000
Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8

{
  "access_token": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx", 
  "scope": "https://mail.google.com/", 
  "token_type": "Bearer", 
  "expires_in": 3599, 
  "refresh_token": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}

However when I used the following code
const { google } = require('googleapis');
const OAuth2 = google.auth.OAuth2;

// Replace these with your credentials and redirect URI
const CLIENT_ID = 'My Client id';
const CLIENT_SECRET = 'my Client secret';
const REDIRECT_URI = 'https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground';

const oAuth2Client = new OAuth2(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, REDIRECT_URI);

// Generate a URL to request authorization
const authUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
  access_type: 'offline',
  scope: ['https://mail.google.com/'],
});

console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url:', authUrl);

// After authorization, you will get a code. Use that code to get the refresh token
const readline = require('readline').createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout,
});

readline.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', async (code) => {
  try {
    const { tokens } = await oAuth2Client.getToken(code);
    console.log('Refresh Token:', tokens.refresh_token);
    readline.close();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error retrieving access token', error);
    readline.close();
  }
});

Two different refresh tokens, I used. One refresh token given by OAuth 2.0 Playground. Other using the link given by the code.
When I used the 1st refresh token, I got the following error.
Enter the code from that page here: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Error retrieving access token GaxiosError: invalid_grant
    at Gaxios._request 

Tried the 2nd way also. Code generated URL to get the refresh token
node .\googleToken.js
Authorize this app by visiting this url: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?access_type=offline&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2F&response_type=code&client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Foauthplayground

Enter the code from that page here: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Error retrieving access token GaxiosError: invalid_grant
    at Gaxios._request
.....

Also in the browser showed similar error message after confirming my account.
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Content-length: 75
X-xss-protection: 0
X-content-type-options: nosniff
Transfer-encoding: chunked
Expires: Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Vary: Origin, X-Origin, Referer
Server: scaffolding on HTTPServer2
-content-encoding: gzip
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Date: Thu, 11 Jul 2024 10:13:28 GMT
X-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
Alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000
Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8

{
  "error_description": "Unauthorized", 
  "error": "unauthorized_client"
}

Gave all the concents. Expect googleapis to give proper access token which can be used for send email.
